# PHP Comet problem

Tags: php

Consider "test.htm" making an Ajax request to "test.php":

test.htm:  **window onload=ajax request( test.php,callback )**
test.php:  **<?php sleep( 20 ); echo "foo"; ?>**

But browser is being reloaded before recieving the response.

When webpage loaded for first time, response was as expected @20.02s

after first refresh: 27s, 
second refresh: 26s,
third refresh: 27s, so on around 27s.

**( Ubuntu 10, Firefox 3.6 )**

This all discrepancy occur, when i reload the page while response is yet to be recieved.
If i reload the page after response from test.php, there is no problem.

**Any remedies/did i go wrong somewhere in backend/ajax is being cached??**

Answer (score 0):

You are making Ajax request to `test.php`, thats why your browser doesn't wait for the response to be received. Make the call Synchronous.

Comment: @Prashanth Everlasto, The browser is being loaded before receiving the response because you are makin Ajax call.. no other reason.

Comment: thanks anyway i fxd it... actually my backend was dealing with a table in database for any changes and respond if change occurs.. and as soon as i request only once from client, the whole thing got hanged down and any further requests were ignored even after page refresh..  the problem was with that backend..